# How to install extensions on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, extensions

I am trying to install an extension for my Magento store. My version of is 
Magento ver. 2.1.15. Now when i install the extension, it is not visible at **Stores->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced**

This is the steps i followed to install the extension

```
 1.Extracted my extension folder into my root            
 2.php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 3.php bin/magento setup:di:compile
 4.php bin/magento cache:clean
```

But i still cannot find the extension in my store. What could be causing this as i am not seeing any error anywhere ?

PS: I just started working on Magento.

**Acl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="GlobalSms_Notify::sms" title="GlobalSms" sortOrder="100">
                    <resource id="GlobalSms_Notify::config" title="Config" sortOrder="10" />
                </resource>
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="GlobalSms_Notify::sms_config" title="Configuration" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Config/etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="globalsms_notify" sortOrder="2000">
            <label>GlobalSms</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="globalsms_notify_configuration" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">

            <label>Basic Configuration</label>
            <tab>globalsms_notify</tab>
            <resource>GlobalSms_Notify::sms</resource>
            <group id="basic_configuration" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label><![CDATA[Basic Configuration&nbsp;&nbsp;<i>Setting API Account</i>]]></label>
                <field id="notify_username" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enter GlobalSms Username</label>
                    <comment>Enter your GlobalSms SMS API Username</comment>
                    <tooltip>Your username must be the same as your GloablSms api username</tooltip>
                    <validate>required-entry</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="notify_password" type="password" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enter GlobalSms Password</label>
                    <comment>Enter your GlobalSms SMS API Password</comment>
                    <tooltip>Your password must be the same as your GlobalSms api password</tooltip>
                    <validate>required-entry</validate>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>


    </system>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all : check if your module has correctly been installed

   Run : `php bin/magento module:status` and check if your module is present in **List of enabled modules:**
2. According to your **xml**, your module configuration, will be present in  :

   `Admin > Stores > Configuration > GlobalSms`

   and not in :

   `Stores->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced`

Something like this :

```
Stores > Configuration >
                       |__ GlobalSms
                               |__ Basic Configuration
                                          |__ Basic Configuration Setting API Account
                                                     |__ Enter GlobalSms Username
                                                     |__ Enter GlobalSms Password
```

About the **installation**, you can install extensions by : **1.** Adding files to your project via FTP, or **2.** via Composer.

Comment: I check and i am not finding my modules in the list of enabled modules. I installed the extention by just git cloning the folder into my root (magento)

Comment: run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` then `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` then `php bin/magento c:c`

Answer (score 1):

At first check location of your module it should be at app/code location if you are not installing without composer. After that just just run php bin/magento module:enable VendorName_ModuleName and flush the cache.

Let me know if amy more help needed.

Comment: I git cloned the module into  `app/code/Magento` and followed the steps in [https://github.com/aref-lazrek/Sms-Global-Notification-for-Magento-2]  but i am still not seeing the extension in my configuration to enable it

Comment: so it means your module location is app/code/Magento/VendorName/ModuleName. If it so then placed it under app/code directly like app/code/VendotName/ModuleName